# Decodable Dictionary [String : Any]

Tags: json, swift, string, dictionary, decodable

I'm trying to consume a JSON Rest API via Swifts Decodable class. The API contains a dictionary with keys as Strings and values that sometimes is a **String** and sometimes is **Bool**. I've created structs for all subtrees of the JSON, but can't figure out how to have a dictionary with values of string **OR** Bool.

It's the images-param (below) that is **[String : String] OR [String : Bool]**.

```
struct Item:Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var priceIcon: String
    var priceIconLink: String
    var images: [String : String]
    var rarity: String
    var type: String
    var readableType: String
}
```

Tried with this but it dosen't conform to Decodable.

```
var images: [String : Any]
```

Example of JSON response

```
"images": {
                "icon": "https://image.fnbr.co/emote/5ae8a0edf3d31bd9cac5b80d/icon.png",
                "png": "https://image.fnbr.co/emote/5ae8a0edf3d31bd9cac5b80d/png.png",
                "gallery": "https://image.fnbr.co/emote/5ae8a0edf3d31bd9cac5b80d/gallery.jpg",
                "featured": false
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED! I did some pre processing of the JSON-string before the parsing. Replaced all false with empty string ("").

Solution:

```
dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: ":false}", with: ":\"\"}", options: .literal, range: nil)
```